# Can't clone private Github repositories over HTTPS

Tags: git, github

I have problems cloning private GitHub Repositories over HTTPS. If i try to clone my repository using:

```
git clone https://github.com/{username}/{repository}
```

i get the error:

```
fatal: remote error: Repository not found
```

when i try to enter my credentials in the request like this:

```
git clone https://{username}@github.com/{username}/{repository}
```

I get the error:

```
fatal: Unable to look up {username}@github.com (port 9418)
```

Cloning over ssh works without. Cloning public repositories also works over https. Does anybody know what i could do?
I'm using windows 10 and git for windows version 2.14.13

Comment: Are you using a proxy? Did you add something unusual in your git configuration? You can check it with `git config -l`. Why `port 9418`in the error message?

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Thank you very much! I didn't use a proxy, but git config -l showed me, that i had a wrong configuration. I had multiple entries for url.https. After deleting them everything works again.

Comment: I've updated my answer to take your problem into account. If it works you can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can clone your repository with:

```
git clone https://username@github.com/username/repo_name
```

It can also help to check your git configuration with:

```
git config -l
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already added the SSH key to my GitHub Account. Cloning also works if I'm using the git@github.com URL instead of https://github.com URL. It just doesn't seem to work with HTTPS

Comment: In what ways SSH keys help with HTTPS URLs? (Hint: ssh has nothing in common with https.)

Answer (score 0):

Recent changes in GitHub security do not allow anymore to use your Password to authenticate when cloning a repo.

To overcome this issue you have to generate a Personal access token and use it in place of your password.

To generate a token:

1. open the menu on top right with your avatar and click  `settings`
2. from your profile settings page click  `Developer Settings` that is the last option in the left menu
3. from the developer setting page click `Personal access token`
4. click on the `generate new token` button
5. select the duration and the access scope you want to give to this token and click on the `Generate token` button

You will be able to see the token only at this time, so use / save it before closing the page.

Now that you have the PAT you can use it in place of the password when cloning or logging in with git clients.
BTW it is better to have a different token for each client.