# Can't clone private repo on github from SourceTree

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

A similar issue is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20718193/2313806) however, my symptoms are a little different and none of the steps there seemed to work.  Nor does the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46999328/2313806) work.

I'm attempting to use SourceTree to clone a private repo belonging to github organization of which I am a part.  I have full permissions to view and commit to the repo, I can see it online when I log in, AND I can clone just fine with the command line and also via the github desktop application.  It only fails in SourceTree.

Further, it is not bad credentials or anything like that, because I can clone, commit and push to my other non-private repos on github using SourceTree with my github credentials.

From the "Clone a Repository" dialog I enter the source URL, which looks something like this:

```
https://github.com/MyOrgName/reponame.git
```

I tab off of that field and it populates the destination path and name fields, but at the bottom of the dialog is a yellow exclamation point with this error:

```
This is not a valid source path / URL
```

If I click the error message, it brings up the "Details" dialog, which states the following (twice for some reason):

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyOrgName/reponame.git/' not found
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyOrgName/reponame.git/' not found
```

I have also tried this by adding my username to the url like so:

```
https://myusername@github.com/MyOrgName/reponame.git
```

but no luck there either.

Comment: Answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718193/issue-with-sourcetree-while-cloning-a-github-repository/20727233#20727233

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with SourceTree while cloning a GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718193/issue-with-sourcetree-while-cloning-a-github-repository)

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Did you ever found a solution for that?

Comment: I have had this issue multiple times with SourceTree, and I've finally moved on and stopped using it. The top answer here does not work, either due to my use of Windows or a more recent version, not sure. ST is a hindrance to the GIT workflow, not a help, and I've had enough of it. I've started using GIT integrated in to my IDE (VS2019) simply because it works reliably and ST does not. It's a shame to dump ST as its UI is better, but it's wasted far too much of my time with its numerous issues.

Comment: you must give application permission on github
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40641849/gitkraken-is-not-showing-repo-i-am-a-contributer-to

Answer (score 96, accepted):

It happens because **Sourcetree** didn't get some private access from **Github** while authenticating. So the solution is very simple.

1. Login to your Github account on any browser.
2. From the top right corner select **SETTINGS**.
3. Now select **DEVELOPER SETTINGS**.
4. From  **DEVELOPER SETTINGS** select **PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN**.
5. Now from **PERSONAL ACCESS TOKEN** select **GENERATE TOKEN**.
6. Fill **Note** as `Sourcetree` and Check All Scopes from the checkbox as shown in the below screenshots.
7. After Click on **Generate Token**.[image]
8. Now Open **Sourcetree**.
9. Click on **Options** in **Tools** menu & Click **add** Account.
10. Select options as shown below screenshot.[image]
11. Enter username as your **Github account username** and password as **Generated Token** from Github.
12. Click on **SAVE** now you might see all your repository are visible and can clone too.

Hope it helps.

Comment: After following above steps don't forget to add your username to git url like this --> myusername@github.com/MyOrgName/reponame.git

Comment: Just a point to add, I got confused for two sections, whether to add upper one or lower one.
The correct is to use upper part of screenshot.

Comment: the Source URL for cloning is https://github-username@github.com/orgname-or-github-username/repo-name

Comment: Works for me 
-->
added account using above 12 steps 
for Clone URL 
https://username@github.com/orgname/project.git

Comment: Note that when creating token you have to select the repo checkbox "Full control of private repositories" to allow private access as OP stated.

Comment: Screenshots are not visible.

Comment: WOrked on MacOS too, thanks!

Comment: For me, related to @vipulkumarmehta comment, but changed the username to the personal access token.

Answer (score 5):

I had same problem. My fix way:

1. Remove user from SourceTree settings (optional, i not sure);
2. Add you account in setting and generate new SSH key (it's a main part of fix);
3. Clone your repo;
4. If SourceTree sill can't clone repo you can try to clone from main page of SourceTree choosing external repos.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't seem to work in my case.  For now, I'm using the GitHub desktop application to clone for this one case.

Comment: Go to Tools > Options > Authentication > Accounts > Set account as Default. In my case Ive multiple accounts. I only need my personal account at most times. By updating it fixed the issue for me

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by adding the remote private repo by cloning with SSH

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem when trying to setup SourceTree on a new Mac computer and I frustratingly spent a whole day trying to figure out what was wrong.

I could connect to my Github account from the account page in SourceTree,
I was also authenticated if I tried `ssh -T git@github.com`, but every time I tried to clone a repo from SourceTree I got the error: *This is not a valid source path / URL*.

Also, every time SourceTree tried to refresh the remote repositories I got the error: *The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.GTMOAuth2 error - 1001.)*, and then it prompted me to sign in again, ending up in a loop.

**What eventually worked for me was changing the SourceTree configuration from using embedded git to using system git**.

This might not be the solution for everyone, but it worked for me.

You find the option in Settings -> Git -> Git version (press the button labeled *Use System Git*).